# Website background image not displayed on whole page

Tags: html, css

My background image on my website is not being displayed on the whole page. It is under the div `.hero-image`

Screenshot of problem: http://prntscr.com/oe6bn7

```
    <div class="hero-image">
        <div class="hero-text">
        <h1>Ruan Kuypers</h1>
        <h2>Websites. Done. Right.</h2>
        <h3>A relighable business partner.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.hero-image{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url("img/Header.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Where is your hero-image div?

Comment: @Maze90 My apology's, I've edited the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the `height: 100%`, the background not being displayed on the whole page because the height of the `.hero-image` element itseft not being reached the whole page. Try this :

```
.hero-image {
  height: calc(100vh - 'your navigation bar height'px);
  /*Other css rule*/
}
```

What the above CSS code does is it set the height of the `.hero-image` element equal to the heigh of the `Browser View Height` subtract the height of your navigation bar. This make your `.hero-image` element take all space left in the browser view